# How to use tkinter's widget.config() to modify separate widgets that were created by the same method?

Tags: python, widget, tkinter, config

I'm pretty new to Python. I can MAKE things work, but I'm never really sure if I'm actually using best practices, so forgive me if I'm not explaining things correctly, or if my code isn't written using best practices. I'm working on it!

I'm trying to figure out how to use tkinter's widget.config() to modify separate widgets that were created by the same method? For example, in the code below, how can I use widget.config() to modify the text in results section 2, r2??

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *

class App():
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.master.title('Question')
        self.create_main_frame()  

    def create_main_frame(self):
        self.main_f = Frame(self.master)
        nb = Notebook(padding=5)
        nb.pack(anchor='w')
        self.tab1(nb)

    def tab1(self, nb):
        tab1_frame = Frame(nb)
        nb.add(tab1_frame, text='Tab 1', underline=0)

        prod_lab = Label(tab1_frame, text='Entry:')
        prod_lab.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=(10,0), pady=(10,5), sticky='e')

        self.product_e = Entry(tab1_frame, width=40)
        self.product_e.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=(0,10), pady=(10,5))

        self.button1 = Button(tab1_frame,
                               text="Run",
                               command=self.run1
                               )
        self.button1.grid(row=2, column=1, padx=(0,10), pady=(0,10), sticky='ne')


        self.results1 = self.create_result(tab1_frame, 'Results Section 1')
        self.results2 = self.create_result(tab1_frame, 'Results Section 2')
        self.results3 = self.create_result(tab1_frame, 'Results Section 3')

    def create_result(self, frame, name):
        lab_frame = LabelFrame(master=frame, text=name)
        lab_frame.grid(sticky='we', padx=10, pady=10, columnspan=10)

        l1 = Label(master=lab_frame, text='Result 1:')
        l1.grid(sticky='e', row=0, column=0, pady=2)

        l2 = Label(master=lab_frame, text='Result 2:')
        l2.grid(sticky='e', row=1, column=0, pady=2)

        l3 = Label(master=lab_frame, text='Result 3:')
        l3.grid(sticky='e', row=2, column=0, pady=2)

        r1 = Label(master=lab_frame, text='')
        r1.grid(sticky='w', row=0, column=1, pady=2)

        r2 = Label(master=lab_frame, text='')
        r2.grid(sticky='w', row=1, column=1, pady=2)

        r3 = Label(master=lab_frame, text='')
        r3.grid(sticky='w', row=2, column=1, pady=2)

    def run1(self):
        #This is the method that will be used to find the results I need
        #For the sake of this question, let's pretend I want to put whatever text is in Entry 1, into results section 2 result 2
        print (self.product_e.get())
        print ('How do I use "widget.config()" to modify the 3 results sections separately???')

master = Tk()
app = App(master)
master.mainloop()
```

Thanks so much in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not good in Tkinter so I would change `create_result()` to class `Results`.

```
from Tkinter import *
from ttk import *

class Results():

    def __init__(self, frame, name):
        self.lab_frame = LabelFrame(master=frame, text=name)
        self.lab_frame.grid(sticky='we', padx=10, pady=10, columnspan=10)

        self.l1 = Label(master=self.lab_frame, text='Result 1:')
        self.l1.grid(sticky='e', row=0, column=0, pady=2)

        self.l2 = Label(master=self.lab_frame, text='Result 2:')
        self.l2.grid(sticky='e', row=1, column=0, pady=2)

        self.l3 = Label(master=self.lab_frame, text='Result 3:')
        self.l3.grid(sticky='e', row=2, column=0, pady=2)

        self.r1 = Label(master=self.lab_frame, text='')
        self.r1.grid(sticky='w', row=0, column=1, pady=2)

        self.r2 = Label(master=self.lab_frame, text='')
        self.r2.grid(sticky='w', row=1, column=1, pady=2)

        self.r3 = Label(master=self.lab_frame, text='')
        self.r3.grid(sticky='w', row=2, column=1, pady=2)

class App():
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.master.title('Question')
        self.create_main_frame()  

    def create_main_frame(self):
        self.main_f = Frame(self.master)
        nb = Notebook(padding=5)
        nb.pack(anchor='w')
        self.tab1(nb)

    def tab1(self, nb):
        tab1_frame = Frame(nb)
        nb.add(tab1_frame, text='Tab 1', underline=0)

        prod_lab = Label(tab1_frame, text='Entry:')
        prod_lab.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=(10,0), pady=(10,5), sticky='e')

        self.product_e = Entry(tab1_frame, width=40)
        self.product_e.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=(0,10), pady=(10,5))

        self.button1 = Button(tab1_frame,
                               text="Run",
                               command=self.run1
                               )
        self.button1.grid(row=2, column=1, padx=(0,10), pady=(0,10), sticky='ne')


        self.results1 = Results(tab1_frame, 'Results Section 1')
        self.results2 = Results(tab1_frame, 'Results Section 2')
        self.results3 = Results(tab1_frame, 'Results Section 3')


    def run1(self):
        #This is the method that will be used to find the results I need
        #For the sake of this question, let's pretend I want to put whatever text is in Entry 1, into results section 2 result 2
        print (self.product_e.get())
        print ('How do I use "widget.config()" to modify the 3 results sections separately???')
        self.results1.r2.config(text='1111111111')
        self.results2.r2.config(text='xxxxxxxxxx')
        self.results3.r2.config(text='----------')

master = Tk()
app = App(master)
master.mainloop()
```

Comment: This worked great. I obviously don't have a complete understanding of when to use new classes vs. methods within a class vs. functions completely outside of classes. Need to do some reading!

Comment: As a follow up question, is there a way to return results2.r2.config before the entire method is complete? In this case, it doesn't really matter, but if each results set took 20 seconds, it would be nice to populate the GUI with each result as it completes instead of waiting for the entire method to complete.

Comment: I thing this required threads - second thread can do something in background and than it have to send result to main thread because only main thread can use GUI. You can have more threads - one for every results set. But threads are more complicated.

Comment: @Bryan Oakley. What do you propose ? Do you have example code ?

Comment: @furas: there's not enough data to answer that question. It all depends on why "each results set took 20 seconds" and whether that could be broken up into smaller chunks, or whether it could be run as a separate process. In either case, that can't be answered in a comment box -- it deserves its own question. There are already questions like that here on this site.